# C++ - function object "equal_to" versus "operator=="

Tags: c++

Given a programmer defined POD `struct` that will be stored in an `unordered_map`, is there any particular advantage in defining:

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct equal_to<MyType> {
        bool operator()(const MyType& lhs, const MyType& rhs) const {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

over simply defining:

```
operator==(const MyType& lhs, const MyType& rhs)
```

(I'm already aware of the potential advantage of using an "inlineable" function object rather than a function pointer for the hashing function).

Comment: `==` may already exist, and not do what you want?

Comment: There is *no* significant difference in inlinability between function objects and true functions. Any compiler that can't inline a named-function pointer is just a toy.

Comment: @Leushenko the `operator==(const T&, const T&)` might be in a separate compilation unit, and therefore only optimisable via link-time optimisation (if enabled, which it usually isn't).

Answer (score 3):

I would say `operator==` has more uses than a specialization of `equal_to<>` because people normally write `a == b`, not `equal_to<T>()(a, b)`. And the default `equal_to<>` is implemented in terms of `operator==`, not the other way around.

If you need to specialize `std::equal_to` because it must behave differently from `operator==`, then a better idea may be to implement a custom `my_equal_to` predicate class, not related to `std::equal_to` in order to follow the principle of least surprise.

Also, there is interface deficiency in `std::equal_to<T>` because it accepts arguments of the same type. C++14 `std::equal_to<void>` fixes the deficiency by accepting arguments of different types and forwarding them to `operator==`.

`operator==`, on the other hand, can have multiple overloads for different types (e.g.  `operator==(std::string const&, char const*)`).

Which means that in C++14 `std::equal_to<void>` and overloaded `operator==` work nicely together, see [N3657 Adding heterogeneous comparison lookup to associative containers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm) for more details.

> I'm already aware of the potential advantage of using an "inlineable" function object rather than a function pointer for the hashing function

Function pointers do not apply here, default `equal_to<>` uses `operator==` directly, not through a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class hierarchy and want to use the `equal_to` of the parent class on two objects of the child class, you may use the `equal_to`-variant, but not the `==` variant (which will choose the comperator for the child class):